# Studio во весь экран

Tags: android, android-studio

Как возможно в студии открывать ide так, чтобы был виден только код на экране, без лишних там вкладок и тому прочее.

ТОЛЬКО КОД

Comment: можно закрыть все вкладки вручную)

Comment: я помню что делал товарищ так, что на весь экран и только код.
чтоб вообще ничего  не отвлекало.
а эти удаленные вкладки потом еще устанешь восстанавливать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шаг 1) нажимаешь ctrl+Ё -> ViewMode -> Enter Presentation Mode
Шаг 2) нажимаешь ctrl+Ё -> ViewMode -> Enter Full Screen

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сочетание клавиш  **Ctrl+Shift+F12** (если у вас windows или linux), или **Cmd+Shift+F12** (если у вас Mac). Должно работать это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, это я тоже нашёл в shortcod'ах на developer'e, но и это не совсем то к сожалению.